# How do I validate the less then zero inputs efficiantly without so many of the same else statements?

Tags: java

I am trying to create a computer simulation of money losses over blackjack games. However I am running into a bug where if I put a less then zero value in one of the prompts, the program has to go through all the other prompts before warning about the less then zero.

Is there a way to immediately warn about less then zero values without having to put the same exact else statement for each if over and over again?

```
private void menu()
{
    boolean NonNumeric=false;
    //This is so a different exception is thrown for the minimum stakes since it's a float.
    boolean isDecimal=false;
    while(getRounds()<=0 || getPlayers()<=0 || getStakes()<=0 )
    {
        try
        {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            if(getRounds()<=0)
            {
                System.out.println("Enter number of rounds.");
                setRounds(input.nextInt());
            }
            if(getPlayers()<=0)
            {
                System.out.println("Enter number of players.");
                setPlayers(input.nextInt());
            }
            if(getStakes()<=0)
            {
                System.out.println("Enter minimum stakes.(Note: All players bet minimum only)");
                isDecimal=true;
                setStakes(input.nextFloat());
            }

        }

        catch (InputMismatchException e ) //In case some idiot enters a letter or symbol.
        {
            //This if statement is so that a different message comes if the invalid entry is a float.
            if(isDecimal==true)
            {
                System.out.println("Entry must be a number. Not a letter or symbol. Try Again.\n");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Entry must be a whole number. Not a letter, decimal, or symbol. Try Again.\n");
            }
            /*This boolean is so that the below if statement does not run if the user enters a letter
            since the integer defaults back to a 0 on exception.*/
            NonNumeric = true;
        }
        if(getRounds()<=0 || getPlayers()<=0 || getStakes()<=0)
        {
            System.out.println("Number must be greater than 0.\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by format? It's indented properly.

Comment: Personally, I'd stop checking for the validity of all of them in a giant loop, and ask for each one individually.

Comment: I feel so stupid now. Why didn't I think of that.

Comment: @DrinkJavaCodeJava: There's 16 spaces of indentation for all but 1 line of the code. I wouldn't call that "properly indented"

Comment: Ill fix this right away.

Comment: Life lesson: don't keep calling yourself stupid; it's stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modularize. Create a method (or even a class) that takes an input and accepts it only if it meets conditions. For example

```
 private int myIntGetter(String caption, boolean forcePositive) {
    System.out.println(caption);
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int intValue = input.nextInt();
    while ((forcePositive) && (intValue <=0)) {
      System.out.println("Number must be greater than \0");
      System.out.println(caption);
      intValue = input.nextInt();
    }
    // here intValue is valid
    return intValue;
  }
```

Comment: Take it even further and create validation routines that can be reused anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not to concerned with being nice to your user:

```
do{
   System.out.println("Enter number of rounds.  Rounds must greater than zero.");
   setRounds(input.nextInt());
}while( getRounds()<=0);
```

You can do that for each thing the user has to enter.  It's quick and dirty.